# View is override when keyboard is displayed in android

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a few view in a RelativeLayout with the align bottom attribute set, when the soft keyboard comes up the views are pushed up by the soft keyboard and override other views so I can't contact with view

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uG0cU.png)

When soft keyboard is displayed

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41ZFl.png)

So I can't cilck button

Comment: can you provide screenshots or sample code?

Comment: Sorry I forgot that, I edited and described in the pictures

Answer (score 0):

add this below line in `manifest` :

`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateAlwaysHidden"`

See full code :

```
<activity android:name=".activity.TermConditionActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateAlwaysHidden"
            ></activity>
```

If suppose above code is not work then paste below line:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

## Update:

Make changes in your `onCreate()` method in the activity class after befor `setContentView()`

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

**OR**

```
windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Comment: thanks you , android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"  is work but ActionBar is hidden so any other way to Actionbar is not hidden ?

Comment: It does not solve the problem when I turn on Soft Keyboard, ActionBar is hidden and when I turn off the keyboard ActionBar appears but I want ActionBar always shows when I turn on or turn of Soft Keyboard

Comment: your action bar is custom or default ??

Comment: My Actionbar is default